# ngx-schema-form: Add custom validation messages (Angular 6)?

Tags: angular, forms, jsonschema

I am using NGX-Schema-Form https://github.com/makinacorpus/ngx-schema-form to render form fields based on a json object.

My question is: How to add custom validation error messages to my schema and also how to display them properly on the ui (`Bootstrap 4.1 based`).

Here is an example of the standard schema format:

**Note:** 
Pattern, minLength, maxLength

```
mySchema = {
"properties": {
    "cellphoneNumber": {
        "type": "string",
        "title": "Cellphone number",
        "placeholder": "e.g. 082 320 2121",
        "widget": {
            "id": "string"
        },
        "pattern": "^\\d{10}$",
        "minLength": 5,
        "maxLength": 12
    }
}
```

But what i would like to do:

```
mySchema = {
"properties": {
    "cellphoneNumber": {
        "type": "string",
        "title": "Cellphone number",
        "placeholder": "e.g. 082 320 2121",
        "widget": {
            "id": "string"
        },
        pattern: {
            value: '^\\d{10}$',
            message: 'Cellphone number must be 10 digits'
        },
        minLength: {
            value: '5',
            message: 'Please enter at least 5 characters'
        }
        maxLength: {
            value: '14',
            message: 'Please enter no more than least 14 characters'
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

And then also how to override the standard string widget to show this error if the form and field is ng-dirty and ng-touched.

Rough example:

```
<div class="error mt-2" *ngIf="control.errors && control.pristine == false || control.touched == true">
  <div *ngFor="let err of control.errors">
    {{ err.message }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Im am looking for a solid solution please for enterprise level implementation.

Comment: Is there anything you have tried in order to achieve this?

Comment: Yes I have tried to display the appropriate message like in my Rough Example but the errors returned is the standard angular pattern, minLength, maxLength errors messages.:

```[
  {
    "code": "PATTERN",
    "params": [
      "^\\d{10}$",
      ""
    ],
    "message": "String does not match pattern ^\\d{10}$: ",
    "path": "#/"
  },```

Comment: I have created my own stringWidget that overrides the standard stringWidget but I am unsure how to resolve the schemas error validation and message to this overridden template.

Comment: @Jean-pauldeBeer Have you managed to resolve this?

Answer (score -2):

You can use **`FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule`** into your app to do so.

Please follow to do so.

**Import `FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule` into your module.ts file.**

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { emailRegexp, passwordRegexp } from '../../constants'; // if you have any email regex for validation otherwise remove it.
```

**Add into @NgModule:**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [
        AppComponent
  ],
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

**Now goto your component where your form needs to valoidate:**

```
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
```

**Initialize in your constructor:**

```
   constructor(
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    ) { }
```

**Create your form validator: ( I am using for login purpose ):**

```
    // login form validations
    this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        email: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required)])], // If you don't have any email regex. otherwise write this=>             email: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern(emailRegexp)])],

        password: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)])]
    });
}
```

**Now create your form ( In HTML ) like this:**

```
    <form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="loginForm.valid && login()" novalidate>
              <div *ngIf="loginError" class="form-group">
                  <div class="">
                    <p class="loginError">Incorrect Email/Password </p>
                  </div>

              <input type="email"  formControlName="email">

            <p *ngIf="loginForm.controls.email.touched && loginForm.controls.email.errors && loginForm.controls.email.errors.pattern"
              class="error-message">
              Invalid Email </p>

            <p *ngIf=" loginForm.controls.email.touched && loginForm.controls.email.errors && loginForm.controls.email.errors.required && !loginForm.controls.email.errors.pattern"
              class="error-message">
              Email is required </p>
          </div>

      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <input autocomplete="off" type="password" (focus)="focusFunction()" placeholder="Password" formControlName="password" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="loginForm.controls.password.touched">
          <p *ngIf="loginForm.controls.password.errors && loginForm.controls.password.errors.required " class="error-message">Password is required </p>
          <p *ngIf=" loginForm.controls.password.errors && loginForm.controls.password.errors.minlength" class="error-message"> Min. 8 characters required.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <button [disabled]="!loginForm.valid" type="submit" >
          <div  class="sign-in">Sign in</div>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for this but this is just standard forms with validation (which I know how to do) but does not relate to my question specifically using NGX-FROM-SCHEMA generating the form dynamically from json and overriding ngx-schema-form string widget.